# How to add custom menu items to system menu?

Tags: 16.04, scripts, menu

I'm wanting to write a few shell scripts which I can run from clicking their respective items from the system menu (with the power options).  I cant seem to find anything online about adding items to it however - is there a file or directory somewhere which contains each of these menu items that I can add to?

Comment: Did you know [Nautilus Actions](http://www.nautilus-actions.org/)? This is not exactly you describe in your issue but maybe can help you.

Comment: I'm using Nautilus Actions Configuration Tool now to get a few custom right-click options, but not for menu items.  I'm not sure if it will work for me, but I'll check it out now.

Comment: This is the [article](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MessagingMenu/). Message menus configuration.

Comment: That article seems to be different.  I'm looking for a file or directly that contains the menu items like 'System Settings...', 'Suspend', etc. which I can edit.  That article is more of a guide to installing a sort of a customizable indicator.

Comment: Ok, Understood now. I also don't know how to change these contents  by the way you asked. But try this  [article](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand)  to change context icons of menu left. Maybe the change of contents you want could be done by a similar way. Good luck on yours new researches.